# Remove surrounding double or single quotes in Golang

Tags: string, go

Shouldn't `strconv.Unquote` handle both single and double quotes?

See also https://golang.org/src/strconv/quote.go - line 350

However following code returns a `syntax error`:

```golang
s, err := strconv.Unquote(`'test'`)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
} else {
  fmt.Println(s)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/TnprqhNdwD1

But double quotes work as expected:

```
s, err := strconv.Unquote(`"test"`)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
} else {
  fmt.Println(s)
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Unquote is for Go syntax literals. From the [Unquote docs](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote): `If s is single-quoted, it would be a Go character literal`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no ready function for what you want in the standard library.

What you presented works, but we can make it simpler (and likely more efficient):

```
func trimQuotes(s string) string {
    if len(s) >= 2 {
        if c := s[len(s)-1]; s[0] == c && (c == '"' || c == '\'') {
            return s[1 : len(s)-1]
        }
    }
    return s
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(trimQuotes(`'test'`))
fmt.Println(trimQuotes(`"test"`))
fmt.Println(trimQuotes(`"'test`))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tyLRGSsY-WP)):

```
test
test
"'test
```

Comment: although your answer is almost identical to mine, except for the downvotes on mine

Answer (score 2):

`strconv.Unquote` does properly handle both single and double quotes, but it isn't intended to be used in the way that your code snippet invokes it. It's intended for use in cases where you are processing go source code, and come across a string literal. The single quote case is valid for a single character, and not a string. In your go source files, if you try to use single quotes for a multi-character string literal, you'll get a compiler error similar to `illegal rune literal`.

What you can do instead for removing quotes from the start and end of a string, is use the `strings.Trim` function to take care of it.

```
s := strings.Trim(`'test'`, `'"`)
fmt.Println(s)
```

Comment: The problem with `strings.Trim()` is that it would turn `"'abc` to `abc` even though in this case asker would want it to remain `"'abc`.

Answer (score 0):

Temp workaround:

```
func trimQuotes(s string) string {
    if len(s) >= 2 {
        switch {
          case s[0] == '"' && s[len(s)-1] == '"':
            return s[1 : len(s)-1]
          case s[0] == '\'' && s[len(s)-1] == '\'':
            return s[1 : len(s)-1]
        }
    }
    return s
}
```

Comment: Why not just use strings.Replace? https://play.golang.org/p/t44oXT987XO

Comment: Also, in 99% of cases where you would otherwise use "else if", it tends to be more idiomatic in Go to use a `switch` statement instead.  They can be slightly more compact in certain situations (especially a string if `||` clauses, since you can just comma separate them in the same case in a switch), and are usually a bit easier to read.  From a compiler standpoint, the two are completely identical, so this is purely a readability thing.  Example using your conditional: https://play.golang.org/p/yZnX-wPFLCv

Comment: @Kaedys - because `Orig: 'te"st' | Unquoted: test`

Comment: Updated to use switch instead of if/else - thanks for comment, but anyone can see `Replace` simply doesn't provide the same behaviour. In any case @jimB provided the expected answer and I'd gladly accept it if he posts it as an answer